# FadeOut/FadeOut not working but show() and hide() do

Tags: jquery, tabs, fadein, fadeout

I have this simple code to create tabs on two divs, but when clicking on the tabs the elements are not fading in or out, however if I change fadeIn and fadeOut to show and hide, it works fine, I don't see what's wrong:

```
  $("ul.tabs li").click(function(event)
                   {
                     event.preventDefault();
                    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(".tab_content").fadeOut();

                    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
                    console.log(activeTab)
                    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        });
    <ul class="tabs">
               <li class="page_item  active">
                                        <a href="#doss" class="option-doss">Doss</a>
                                    </li>
                <li class="page_item competitors-page">
                                        <a href="#competitors" class="option-competitors">Competitors</a>
                                    </li>
</ul>
    <div id="doss" class="tab_content clearfix"> 
                        <div class="men">
                             <a href="?cat=28"></a>
                         </div>
                        <div class="women">
                            <a href="?cat=37"></a>
                        </div>
                         <div class="kids">
                            <a href="?cat=44"></a>
                         </div>
                </div>
                <div id="competitors" class="tab_content clearfix">
                    competitors
                </div>
```

**RESOLVED**

I removed the easing.js file and it seemed to work.

Comment: Try passing some parameters to the function? Fast, slow see if that rectifies it? Also check the console for a debug issue

Comment: works fine for me => http://jsfiddle.net/sYZbD/

Comment: @user1937021, maybe you testing on ie7?

Comment: could it be conflicting with other ajvascript I have because it's weird it works for LifeInTheGrey

Comment: Yeah works for me too.

http://jsfiddle.net/ra4sp/

Are you wrapping that in a $(document).ready() ?

Check your console on Chrome or Firefox and say us what it's given !

Which version of jQuery are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jquery are you using?

If you have an ancient jquery version, you might need to add an extra reference to the jquery easing plugin...

See:

1. http://matthewlein.com/experiments/easing.html
2. http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Easing
3. https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing

Answer (score -1):

Your activeTab variable is an URL, it should be a reference to a DOM element.

Instead of

```
$(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Which evaluates to $('?cat=n').fadeIn();
```

Do something like:

```
$(".tab_content").fadeIn();
```

Comment: my activeTab is equal to doss or competitors